# handling data set with horrible date time data

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, numpy, julian-date

I have a huge `sensor data` set and working on `Python`. The problem is their `date formats`. Basically,this is how the date columns look like;

```
07/ 7/15 06:51

07/ 7/15 06:53

07/ 7/15 06:55

07/ 7/15 06:57

07/ 7/15 06:59

2015-07-07 07:00:46.047

07/ 7/15 07:03

07/ 7/15 07:05

07/ 7/15 07:07

07/ 7/15 07:09

07/ 7/15 07:11

07/ 7/15 07:13

2015-07-07 07:15:53.007

2015-11-14 23:33:43.000

2015-11-14 23:35:44.000

2015-11-14 23:37:43.000

2015-11-14 23:39:43.000

2015-11-14 23:41:43.000

11/14/15 23:42

2015-11-14 23:45:43.000

11/14/15 23:46

2015-11-14 23:49:43.000

2015-11-14 23:51:44.000
```

I am going to parse dates to use weekdays, weekends and as an extra maybe I will turn them a `Julian date format` (which uses numbers 1 to 365 instead of regular dates).

I had tried to :

- Parsing dates while I am reading csv
- Date until parser; e.g. dateutil.parser.parse(x)
- Datetime.strptime

but none of them worked. I still cannot parse dates. 
These data in 10 part excel files.

When I read them with `pd.read_csv(......, parse_dates('date'))`, it reads date columns as `'object'` in some files and as `'datetime64'` format in other files. But even if the files with format `'datetime64'` date's cannot parse and it gives an error :

> "Unknown String Format".

Any idea would help!

Comment: Are all of the dates either day-month-year or year-month-day, where the punctuating character might not be a hyphen and the lengths of the strings representing days, months and years might vary?

Comment: Alternatively, can we rely on the apparent ordering of the dates as a guide?

Comment: what do you mean by 'can we rely on..?" @BillBell

Comment: Will the dates be in order?

Comment: yes they are in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably going to have to munge this with several approaches I haven't done a significant amount of testing but I was able to convert 2 of your different dates(`07/ 7/15 06:51`, `2015-11-14 23:45:43.000`) to datetime objects using:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dateutil.parser.parse(date).timestamp())
```

The `date` parameter inside the `parser.parse` method would be the varied string format you have for dates.

There might be a better way to do this but try using this approach as a lambda method on the date column to see the result.

```
df_date = df['date'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dateutil.parser.parse(d).timestamp())
```

Comment: not working it gives an AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'  @SeanParsons

Comment: I had a typo in the code, try again. import the `dateutil` module and the `datetime` module, then try using the block of code I have in my answer.

Comment: You have missing parenthesis at last but this is not the problem, it has still same problem : " type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' "

Comment: Excuse-me, but why the roundtrip of `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dateutil.parser.parse(date).timestamp())` if `dateutil.parser.parse` **already** returns a datetime object??

Comment: Your right, I was reading others solutions online for converting strings to datetime objects and that was one that I saw that worked. Although Nezhat if you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) the datetime object does have a datetime attribute.

Comment: dateutil.parser.parse is not returns a datetime object in all parts of data. In some files it turns just object and other files it turns datetime64 format. And in the files which turns datetime object, they still cannot parsed with error message : Unknown String Format.  @jsbueno

Comment: I think the problem which cause the error"Unknown String Format"  is multi date format in one file some of them has hour some of them separated with hyphen etc.

Comment: Nice. so the timestamp is needed.  Anyway, there is no "full auto" here - the OP will have to create a if/elif chain to identify the base pattern for each date in order to safely parse them .

Answer (score 1):

If we make the assumption that the formats presented are the only two formats used, the following may do the trick. Just read the data in as strings and then we'll parse from there.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['07/7/15 06:51', '07/7/15 06:59', '2015-07-07 07:00:46.047',
                            '11/14/15 23:42', '2015-11-14 23:45:43.000']})

# mask the df based on the date formats
dash_mask = df['date'].str.contains('-')
slash_mask = df['date'].str.contains('/')

# use the masks to apply pd.to_datetime() to only one format at a time
df.loc[dash_mask, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[dash_mask, 'date'],
                                               infer_datetime_format=True)
df.loc[slash_mask, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[slash_mask, 'date'],
                                               infer_datetime_format=True)

>>> df['datetime'].dt.date
0    2015-07-07
1    2015-07-07
2    2015-07-07
3    2015-11-14
4    2015-11-14
```

Of course, this could be turned into a function and could accommodate more date formats using a similar approach, but this should get the job done. I'll grant it isn't pretty...

By the way, if you only care about the date and not the time during the day, you could strip that part out if it's causing problems in parsing the dates.

```
df['only_date'] = df['date'].str.split(' ').str[0]
>>> df
                      date   only_date
0            07/7/15 06:51     07/7/15
1            07/7/15 06:59     07/7/15
2  2015-07-07 07:00:46.047  2015-07-07
3           11/14/15 23:42    11/14/15
4  2015-11-14 23:45:43.000  2015-11-14
```

Comment: Thank you very much your code help me to handle half of my data! What I mean is, like I mentioned it reads some files date column as 'datetime64' format and others as 'object' format. Your code is working on the ones datetime64 formats. The other which is in object form has an error : Unknown String Format

Comment: Hmmm, that should work on strings as well. Try adding the `error='coerce'` option to the `pd.to_datetime()` function. There must be some bad strings that don't have any recognizable format. You could then look at which rows are missing the 'datetime' column you created to see if there's another format you could accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that your data is in a variety of different formats.  So instead of hoping some package can deduce the right format, you could `try` parsing using each of the different formats you expect, and take the one that works.